# "Redirect Loop" when creating a multisite

Tags: multi-sites, subsites

I know there are a few questions related to this one, yet I haven't been able to answer mine.

I want to develop 2 websites pointing to the same Drupal core files,

so :

drupal1.example.com should point /www/dev/sites/drupal1.example.com drupal2.example.com should point to /www/dev/sites/drupal2.example.com

1. I've created both subdomains to point to /www/dev/ folder.
2. I've put settings.php in drupal1.example.com and default.settings.php in drupal2.example.com
3. When I load drupal2.example.com, I get a "Redirect Loop" error.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks!

**ANSWER :**

When there was no settings.php file in my sites/drupal2.example.com folder, it showed the drupal1.example.com website.

When there was a settings.php file in my sites/drupal2.example.com folder, it got me an infinite loop.

So I modified the settings.php in sites/drupal2.example.com folder to connect to a different empty databse, but then I got an error "Base table or view not found: 1146" then another error upon refresh "error: Class 'SelectQueryExtender' not found".

It seemed as though the installer had a hard time loading the 2nd instance of Drupal since there were no tables in the DB.

So I imported DB #1 into DB #2 and it worked.  I could change the theme in drupal2.example.com and I still had the old theme in drupal1.example.com.

The only downside is that I have to delete the content types, nodes, menus, etc ... in my drupal2 but I least it's working!

Comment: If you want to keep the name of your site private, I suggest that you check your post again :)

Comment: Pointing `/www/dev/sites/drupal1.example.com` to `/www/dev/` sounds dodgy.

Comment: @coleopterist - have you ever been on example.com ? :o)

Comment: @coleopterist I want both subdomains to point to Drupal's root installation folder (/www/dev/) so that Drupal spits out the right sites (in the sites/ folder) for the right subdomain.

Comment: My bad - I thought you were symbolic linking them; and I was talking about itx-****.com. You missed a spot.

Comment: if that's the answer...could you please put it as an answer and check it as solved...it will help others to identify quickly the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` properly defined in Apache, I suspect you have the default canonical URL redirects enabled in your .htaccess.  Make sure this stuff is all commented out:

```
  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also make sure you don't have any other Apache rules that are doing something similar, and that you don't have any modules (eg, [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) or [Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools)) or custom code that would do a redirect.

Comment: Thanks!  I've disabled the clean URLs in the default installation and have uncommented the lines :
`#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
#   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`
But now I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error to access "/install.php" .. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared host and have installed Drupal through a Script check if `install.php` is in the document root.

If not, download Drupal, extract `install.php` and put it in the document root. Now go to the site and the installer should work.